# Make vscode typing same as terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Well, when i typing on my terminal, the current type location look like this:
[image]

But in vscode look like this:
[image]

How i change my vscode to look like my terminal?

Comment: if you use the caret you KNOW where the character will get inserted, VSC does not have overwrite mode

Answer (score 1):

Solved by go to setting, type cursor style, then change it to block

[image]